# Improve Efficiency of 'Transactions Last Hour' (or 'Date Between') Query

Tags: sql-server

Found that queries to this very large table (~100 million records) are inefficient (often 20-30 seconds but can be more), but not sure what to do about it:

```
SELECT @TRXCOUNT = count(1)
FROM inbound.[Transaction] WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE CreatedTimeStamp BETWEEN DATEADD(HH, - 1, SYSDATETIME()) AND SYSDATETIME()
```

The execution plan shows Index Scan (NonClustered) Cost 93%

Comment: Do you have an index on the `CreatedTimeStamp` column?

Comment: I have three indexes; one of them has `CreatedTimeStamp` as the 'Included' column. In another, it's listed as one of two 'Index key columns' on the General tab of Index Properties in SSMS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like from your comment that you don't have an index based on `CreatedTimeStamp`. Having it included in another index doesn't make your query more efficient - a table scan is still currently required.

I suggest you add a new index (e.g. called `IX_Inbound_Transaction_CreatedTimeStamp`).  It doesn't need to be clustered as the index is all the query will need to look at.

Comment: No it doesn't.  I suspect in your case it shouldn't be either as duplicate `CreatedTimeStamp` entires are most likely possible.

Comment: Thanks - that's what I figured and so I didn't click the button. Takes a long time, so we'll see how it turns out. Thank you.

Comment: With an index there is no difference in the query time, but with an index and replacing `SYSDATETIME()` with ` GETDATE()` the difference is enormous - anyone know why? thanks!

Comment: It's actually not just replacing SYSDATETIME(), it's something more. If the functions are used consistently, the query is still quick. And if I compare with the GETDATE inside of the DATEADD it's still fast. But this is slow: `DATEADD(MINUTE,-5, SYSDATETIME()) AND GETDATE()` I'm guessing it has something to do with having to perform the conversion twice; and maybe it's a lot easier to one way than the other due to precision.

Comment: I feel like there ought to be a way to create a filtered index for something like this where it filters to only include the most recent data and doesn't index the 99 million records that weren't created in the last hour. But this doesn't seem to exist. Seems like a waste.

Answer (score 1):

You cloud try two things:

1. Calculate the value of DATEADD(HH, - 1, SYSDATETIME()) before, store it in variable and use variable in query. I know, it should not matter, but You can always check it.
2. Check if Your index on CreatedTimeStamp is healthy (You got one there, right?). Some help from [fine manual](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189858.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Greater Than may be quicker than BETWEEN.

```
SELECT @TRXCOUNT = count(1)
FROM inbound.[Transaction] WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE CreatedTimeStamp > SYSDATETIME() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE
```

Syntax may not be exact.  mySQL vs SQL